# Associating string positions before and after changes

Tags: algorithm

I have a UTF-8 string with multi line text. I perform some preprocessing on it that changes lengths and adds/removes characters.
Something like replacing `\r\n` with `\n`.
How do I associate positions in the new string with positions in the old so my code would be able to say "invalid syntax at position X" and that position would be in the original string so the user would have no issues finding the character that triggered the error?

Comment: Options include communicating *line number* and *position in line* or *including some context*.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you never add / delete lines.
So this is the simpler problem of "map old char positions to new ones within a line", L times for the L lines.

You start with a line of N characters, and make changes to it.
Initialize a vector `idx` which counts from 0 .. N-1,
indicating the i-th "new" character corresponds to old character `i`.
Phrase your text updates as some sequence of

- delete K characters at J
- insert K characters at J
- substitute K characters at J

Only the 1st two affect `idx`.

When deleting, write NULL tombstones on the deleted indices
and decrement remaining `idx` entries by K.

When inserting do the opposite, incrementing entries by K.
There is the wrinkle of deciding what values new entries should have --
probably J (repeated) is the value that makes the most sense for your application.

---

Perhaps you have been using string comparisons,
maybe a regex substitution, to edit the line.
If so, you will need to identify (J, K) values.
One approach would be to include a
sentinel value as part of each update,
some value that's never seen in the original text.
Then it's easy
to locate it, issue a delete_sentinel operation, and carry on.

---

If you don't get to observe the edit operations,
so you only have the old and new strings,
then things become more difficult.
Myers describes [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and Its Variations](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) to address this problem.